# Mount ADLS Gen2 Storage - File must be dbfs or s3n: /

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to mount ADLS Gen2 Storage in Databricks with this code:

```
%python

configs = {
  "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net": <storage-account-key>,
  "spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net": <storage-account-key>
}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/aaa",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

But I get:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what can be root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Mount ADLS Gen2 Storage in Databrick**

There are two scenarios you can Mount and implement ADLS Gen2 Storage in Databrick.

> **Scenario 1:**

Directly take the Access key from ADLS Gen2 Blob Storage past in `<storage-account-Access key>` of `extra_configs` as shown in the create mount.

**Syntax**

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<Scope-Name>",key="Key_Value"))
```

[image: Ref1]

***Create Mount***

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/io243",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<storage-account-Access key>"})
```

[image: Ref2]

> **Scenario 2:**

Go to the ***Access Keys*** and ***copy the key*** -> ***Create Secret*** for Access Key in ***Azure Key Vault*** .

[image: Ref3]

Create an ***Azure Key Vault*** and [***Secret Scope***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-ui) -> ***Create Scope*** -> Enter the ***DNS Name***
(for ***Example***, `https://databrickskv.vault.azure.net/`) and ***Resource ID*** -> Go to ***Properties tab*** of an Azure Key Vault in your ***Azure portal*** you get both ***DNS*** and ***Resource ID***.

[image: Ref4]

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
            source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
            mount_point = "/mnt/io243",
            extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "databricks-secret-scope", key = "blob-container-key")}
```

[image: Ref5]

**Reference:**

https://bigdataprogrammers.com/create-mount-point-in-azure-databricks/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeNgrBxHmCc

Comment: the issue was with invalid account key but thank you for complex answer, I will put sensitive data inside secret scope instead of keeping in cluster configuration