# Authentication of Azure databricks to Azure Storage account

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-authentication, azure-storage-account

I need to access my Azure Storage Account from the Azure Databricks notebook.

From authentication side, all key dependant methods (SAS, key based authentication) worked but we can't expose the Access Credentials from Storage Account into the notebook.

Is there an option du Authenticate the Databricks on Storageaccount over Service Principal or Managed Identity.

As goal, the notebook in Databricks shall only use this code and use the assigned Service principal / Managed identity (developer doesn't see credentials)?

[image]

These are possible options for authentication for us:
[image]

Comment: Not sure about the managed identity, but can you please clarify about not exposing the Access Credentials in the notebooks ? Maybe you can try adding the credentials to the keyvault and then link it to a secret scope and use that in the notebooks ? Will that work ? Refer to the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope Apologies if it is not applicable...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access storage account with service principle.

**Please follow these steps:**

- Create service principle account with azure AD app registration
- Create storage account and grant service principle access to storage account.
- Add application secrete to key vault.
- Create key vault secrete scope with Databricks.

For more information refer this [Blob](https://towardsdatascience.com/mounting-accessing-adls-gen2-in-azure-databricks-using-service-principal-and-secret-scopes-96e5c3d6008b) by Dhyanendra Singh Rathore and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035755/mount-adls-gen2-storage-file-must-be-dbfs-or-s3n/72036988#72036988) thread.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would stick to the official Azure documentation, they keep updating all their docs constantly, while other personal blogs rarely do it.
For what you need, you have enough with this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/connect/storage/azure-storage

Read the first section, basically Microsoft recommends this order:

1. OAuth 2.0 with a Microsoft Entra ID service principal
2. Shared access signatures (SAS)
3. Account keys

So, to simplify, go with the OAuth solution using an Azure service principal. They put all snippets you need, it's basically copy&pase and then adapt some strings.

But let's say you still want to use SAS solution but don't want the SAS keys to be exposed in the notebook, then you can hide them by using Databricks Secrets:  https://docs.databricks.com/en/security/secrets/index.html
Start by defining on Databricks the Secret value for the SAS string, and then get its value in the notebook using the code you can see in the first link I provided, the SAS token section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/connect/storage/azure-storage#sastokens