# Access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using the account key

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to retrieve all paths to directories in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using method specified in doc: https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/azure-storage.html , in particular I'm trying to access only using the storgae account key (not via Azure service principals or SAS tokens).

The doc says the we just need to set this conf:

```
spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net",
    dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>", key="<storage-account-access-key>"))
```

But nonetheless I'm getting 403 permssion error:

```
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils.ls.
: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, GET, https://<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<my-container>?upn=false&resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&timeout=90&recursive=false, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:ef2753bb-501f-00bf-3c6c-26d7f4000000 Time:2023-01-12T09:56:54.1924327Z"
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:248)
```

how come I'm still getting the error if I only use storage key? I'm a bit confusing becasue using service principal I have to grant the client_id on the storage but in this case what I have to grant? I'm just using the key..

any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Do you have Blob Storage Contributor permission? Contributor isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results**

Go to storage account -> IAM -> **+Add**  Storage Blob Contributor.

[image]

> **Configure storage account in two ways.**

with key vault

```
spark.conf.set( "fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope_name>", key="<Access_key>"))
```

without key vault

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net","Access_key")
```

[image]

for more information refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035755/mount-adls-gen2-storage-file-must-be-dbfs-or-s3n/72036988#72036988) thread.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My question is about what should I have to grant, my personal user that execute the query? Because I know that with service principal i have to grant the app_id but in this case I do not have any app_id

Comment: hi @Salvatore Nedia, you can use in two different ways using access key or service principle. Please Confirm what are you using ?

Comment: I want to use only access key but I'm getting 403

Comment: the question is what I have to grant as Storage Blob Contributor?

Comment: yes, grant Storage Blob Contributor as shown in the above image.

Comment: maybe I haven't been clear :). I have to give grant to what? an user, an app, a group? the problem is grant what? I don't think my Ad account that run the notebook cell..

Comment: To user ,Please follow this process. Go to my  **Storage Account**->  Go to  **Access Control (IAM)**->  Add a new  **Role Assignments**-> Select  **Storage Blob Data Contributor**->  Click on  **Select members(user)** ->  **Review + assign**

Comment: okay, the user in the example image you have hidden?