# AzureKeyVault cannot authenticate from databricks rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

We have been using rstudio provided by Azure Databricks. We are trying to use AzureKeyVault library and call the secrets and keys from Key vault in Azure. It works fine when I run it from local rstudio but it doesn't work when I call the Keyvault from rstudio in databricks.

```
library(AzureKeyVault)
vault <- key_vault("https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net")
```

We are not sure if its a databricks issue or something else?? Has anyone every tried to authenticate the keyvault from databricks rstudio ???

We have been trying this since last week

Comment: Welcome to SO Mahesh. There's a tag [azure-databricks] be worth adding too.

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah have added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a [secret scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-ui)

There DNS name is Vault URI in Key vault (In Creating Scope).

[image]

Then execute below code:

```
%r
    l <- as.list(dbutils.secrets.get(scope = 'rithwik', key = 'Rithwik-key'))
    y <- sub("\\s+$", "", gsub('(.{1})', '\\1 ', x))
    y
```

[image]

**References taken from:**

- [apache spark - Mount ADLS Gen2 Storage - File must be dbfs or s3n: / - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035755/mount-adls-gen2-storage-file-must-be-dbfs-or-s3n/72036988#72036988) For creating Scope.

Comment: Hi Rithwik, We did create the secret scope. It works perfectly fine on Databricks. The issue is when we are trying from rstudio(hosted on Databricks) !! Since dbutils doesnot work on rstudio .