# Create or replace table issue in Azure databrick

Tags: azure, databricks

I am not able to update a script where using create or replace -
''''
create or replace table tablexxx;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablexxx USING DELTA LOCATION '$datalake/location';
''''

Comment: Can you share any errors? That you're facing?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai It is saying SQL parsing error - very generic -- Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input ' ' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 58) == SQL == CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE

Comment: the above error happens sometimes there is a missing or incorrect keyword or symbol, such as a missing comma or parentheses.

Comment: @SaiVamsi i tried below -CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tb_Factxyzxyzxyz USING DELTA OPTIONS ('path' 'abfss://lakedev@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/dev/xyz'); but error is still -- Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input ' ' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 41) == SQL == CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE

Comment: @RubenSo Does the path have file in delta format ? Have you tried providing the schema and then creating as shown in the below answer ? Because when I try creating pointing an empty path I get the error - `Table schema is not provided. Please provide the schema of the table when using REPLACE table and an AS SELECT query is not provided.`

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code. Its working fine for me:**

```
%sql

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table3 (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)
USING DELTA
OPTIONS (
  'path' 'mnt/location/table2'
)
```

[image]

Comment: used follwoing 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tb_Factxyzxyzxyz USING DELTA OPTIONS ('path' 'abfss://lakedev@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/dev/xyz');'    but error is still -- Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input ' ' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 41)

Comment: You can resolve this issue in two ways .first configure storage account  `spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account-Name>.dfs.core.windows.net","Access_key")` replace abfss URL. For more info refer this [MS_doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage#---access-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-with-unity-catalog-external-locations).

Comment: Second approach  mount your storage account replace location path. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035755/mount-adls-gen2-storage-file-must-be-dbfs-or-s3n/72036988#72036988) thread.